# Make CMake do a evaluate and format on an string

Tags: string, variables, cmake

I have a problem where I get an input to a variable `CONFIG_VAR` which looks like this `'$ENV{FOO}/path'`. I want to make CMake evaluate/format this string to replace `'$ENV{FOO}'` to the Environmental variable `FOO=bar`. This variable is coming from Kconfig(if that matters anything) when i print it out it's just a pure string.

I've tried to do `${CONFIG_VAR}` this yields `'$ENV{FOO}/path'` I've tried to do `${${CONFIG_VAR}}` this yields empty . As expected as you are trying to find variable `$ENV{FOO}/path` which does not exist. I've gotten so far to do a REGEX match which gets out `$ENV{FOO}` but doing `${$ENV{FOO}}` did still not evaluate to what I wanted. So I wonder if there is a way to trigger CMake's string formatting to replace the variables in a string in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems hard to implement a eval-like function inside CMake, but you can write your expression to a file by `configure_file`, `file(WRITE)` or `file(APPEND)`, then `include` that file.

Comment: Yeah couldn't find any eval functions and every part of the internet I've looked around says the same. Thanks for the answer.